# Reference to this not type checked

Tags: typescript

In the following code the call `add(n, this)`  does not raise an error 
where `this` is type Object:

```
var add = (n1: number, n2: number): number => n1 + n2;

var o = {
  bias: 42,
  addBias: function(n: number): number {
    return add(n, this);            // No error.
//    return add(n, this.bias);       // This is the correct code.
  }
};

alert(o.addBias(10));   // Displays '10[object Object]'.
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `this` is inferred to be of type `any`. And `any` is compatible with everything in both directions e.g.

```
var foo = 123;
var bar:any;

// Allowed
bar = foo = bar;
```

If you hover over it you would see it :

[image]

TypeScript doesn't infer the meaning of `this` in object literals and assumes them to be `any`.

`this` is only inferred in classes and even then you need to be careful : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1 (its just the way JavaScript works).